# Is there a good way to use a Node.js package from a Java program?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, npm

I am extending a server that is written in Java, and I found a really good Node.js package on npm which provides an API that I'd like to call from the Java server.

How can I implement the "bridge" between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options I can think of.

1. wrap your module with a server and listen for requests. then return the results back to the java process.
2. execute a child process. The stdout/stderr will be returned to java process.

Personally, I would prefer option #2. As mentioned above this will require an installation of v8 javascript engine.

Example:

```
//process.js
console.log('process running');
console.log(process.argv);
console.error(new Error('process error'));
process.exit(0);
```

Run the program from your java code

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("node", "process", "one", "three", "five")
Process p = pb.start();
//Get output from p
```

The stdout should be:

```
process running
[ 'node.exe',
  'process',
  'one',
  'tew',
  'three']
```

The stderr should return:

```
Error: process error
    at Object.<anonymous> (./process.js:5:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. If you don't mind, could you elaborate a little bit on option #2? I'm not really familiar with Node.js and with the method you described there.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to wrap the node.js package in a node.js program and make an API available from that program that can call the functions in the module, probably accessing it via a web server (but any interprocess communication mechanism can be made to work).  Then, you'd have to run the node.js program first and then your Java app could access the node.js functionality via the node.js server.

It takes a node.js interpreter to run node.js Javascript and you only get one of those by running a separate node.js process.  So, you can't directly build a bridge from Java to Javascript in the same process.  You have to create a Javascript process and then communicate with that separate process.